# How can I bomb the Deku Like?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

I've been playing through the Forest Temple in Twilight Princess (the Wii version).  I rescued four monkeys, and now I have to go back and bomb another Deku Like with a bombling spider thing, according to the walkthrough. I've tried so many times, and I'm pretty sure I've died five or six times trying to pick up the bombling, carry it around the bridge, and throw it into the Deku Like.  Every single time, it explodes before I can reach the spot where I can throw it.  And it keeps attacking me, too!  Why they couldn't have just used Bomb Flowers I'll never know.
The specific Deku Like I'm trying to blow up is blocking a chest.  Do I really need the contents of that chest?  Is there any way to skip this part?

Comment: I learned that this part is indeed skippable.  But I forgot to save... Oh well.

Comment: I think I remember that one, if you climb a bit higher up in that room there's another bombling and a spot where you can drop it down.